# I'm trying to copy one table using into statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

But take more time to copying. In this table 2 Non clustered index.Table consist around 20 million records (50 columns).

why its take time ? what i have to check for this ?

Guide me any one.

My query : Select * into table_bkp from table (nolock)

Comment: Have you considered SSIS as an option. It's probably better suited to the volume you're looking at here.

Comment: Thanks. But we can't implement this in ssis. Because this portion we called in one consolidate procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing a one large neverending transaction, another variety would be delete of large number of rows from a table.

The solution, if T-SQL it has to be, is to partition the insert somehow -- by date or by some other appropriate key in the data -- and do inserts 5-10 thousand rows at a time. It will allow transaction log to function normally and speed up the operation significantly.

Comment: this query used only for back up for our safer side . we didn't used any where. If any thing wrong while updating and inserting

Comment: Check also if you can achieve minimal logging (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/23/minimal-logging-changes-in-sql-server-2008-part-2.aspx)